Text in "input" component not being rendered properly
In my nextjs app with typescript, I have a main page.tsx importing a InputField component that has a  (textbox) in it. When typing in the textboxes, the text isn't being rendered.
"use client"

import InputField from "@/components/InputField";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Home() {
  const url = "http://localhost:8080/form/submit";

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    position: ""
  });

  const handleInput = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const fieldName = e.target.name;
    const fieldValue = e.target.value;

    setFormData((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [fieldName]: fieldValue
    }));

  }

  const [ formSuccess, setFormSuccess ] = useState(false);

  const submitForm = (e: any) => {
    // prevents to reload the page after submission (which is the default behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    const formURL = e.target.action;
    // turns formData state into a FormData object
    const data: { [key: string]: string } = {};
    Object.entries(formData).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      data[key] = value
    })

    fetch(formURL, {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    }).then(() => {
      setFormData({
        name: "",
        email: "",
        position: ""
      })
      setFormSuccess(true);
    })
  }

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", height: "100vh" }}>
      {formSuccess ? 
        <div style={{ padding: "10px 20px", backgroundColor: "#565656", borderRadius: "5px"}}>
          <h2 >Formulário enviado com sucesso!</h2>
        </div>
      :
        <form method="POST" action={url} onSubmit={submitForm}>
          <InputField type="text" label="Nome" value={formData.name} onChange={handleInput} />
          <InputField type="text" label="Cargo" value={formData.position} onChange={handleInput} />
          <InputField type="text" label="Email" value={formData.email} onChange={handleInput} />

          <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", alignItems: "center" }}>
              <button type="submit" style={{ padding: "10px 20px", backgroundColor: "#007bff", color: "#fff", border: "none", borderRadius: "5px", cursor: "pointer" }}>Enviar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
      }
    </div>
  );
}


interface InputFieldProps {
    type: string;
    label: string;
    value: string;
    onChange: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
}

const InputField: React.FC<InputFieldProps> = (props) => {
    return(
        <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", alignItems: "center" }}>
            <label>{props.label}</label>
            <input 
                type={props.type} 
                value={props.value} 
                onChange={props.onChange} 
                style={{ color: "black" }}
            />
        </div>
    )
}

export default InputField;


I assume is something regarding handleInput method.
I already checked the color and is not the issue. Also viewing the components via React dev tools they look fine and the console doesn't accuse anything.


In your useState your keys are name, email, & position. However, in your InputField you don't have the "name" field set to those keys. Unless under the hood the InputField maps "label" to "name" I assume that's where the issue is

would have to see InputField component to make sure, but I think you may have to pass in some prop to represent the name, I don't think label will do that by default, but if its a custom component you can make it do that, but generally probably better to have explicit name prop. And that gets passed to input element name attribute. Because event.target I think will be based on name attribute of input element.
